# Can I define 2 structures of the same type in different files where I want to pass one structure to another?

Tags: c, struct

I have two header files as mentioned below:

#### file1.h

```
typedef struct can_type {
  int x;
  float y;
} M_can_type;
```

#### file2.h

```
typedef struct can_type {
  int x;
  float y;
} can_type;
```

Can I define both structures of the same type in different files given as above where I want to pass one structure to another? Also how to map two different type structures to the same type so that I can pass elements of one structure to other?

Comment: you can create one global.h file where u include these two files and define these structure variables as extern , then u can access those any where in file... but for mapping i am not sure..

Comment: What do you mean pass one structure to another? At any given point of time/ visibility only one item should be active

Comment: The question is why you would need to do this though. It's an indication of poor program design.

Comment: @sanjeev No, creating a "global.h" is awful practice, which creates a tight coupling between every single, non-related file in the project. Never do that.

Comment: @Sanjeev i can understand your comments. I have to follow the same pattern as its clients all ready existing designed structure and we cant change full.

Comment: I usually handle this type of problem by declaring (and passing) the argument as a void *ptr, and then casting it any way I like inside the function. For example, int func(void *arg){ mystruct2 *ptr2 = (mystruct2 *)arg; etc;}  And the calling function would have { mystruct1 *ptr1; ... value=func((void *)ptr1); ...} So the calling func() interprets whatever it's passed as a mystruct2 ptr. And it's up to you to make sure mystruct1 and mystruct2 are the same (or similar enough for func's purposes).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is legal.  Indeed, it is necessary.  And it is explicit in the standard, but it is in one of the more turgid and nearly incomprehensible sections of the standard.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type
>
> ¶1 Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional rules for determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers, in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.6 for declarators.<sup>55)</sup> Moreover, two structure, union, or enumerated types declared in separate translation units are compatible if their tags and members satisfy the following requirements: If one is declared with a tag, the other shall be declared with the same tag. If both are completed anywhere within their respective translation units, then the following additional requirements apply: there shall be a one-to-one correspondence between their members such that each pair of
>   corresponding members are declared with compatible types; if one member of the pair is declared with an alignment specifier, the other is declared with an equivalent alignment specifier; and if one member of the pair is declared with a name, the other is declared with the same name. For two structures, corresponding members shall be declared in the same order. For two structures or unions, corresponding bit-fields shall have the same
>   widths. For two enumerations, corresponding members shall have the same values.
>
> <sup>55)</sup> Two types need not be identical to be compatible.

The section from 'Moreover' onwards discusses the situation you are asking about.

Note that although you have two different typedef names (`M_can_type` and `can_type`) in your two headers, the structures that are defined meet the requirements.  Remember, typedef names are only aliases for existing other types (so `M_can_type` is an alias for `struct can_type` in files that include `file1.h` and `can_type` is an alias for `struct can_type` in files that include `file2.h`).  Because each header defines the structure type, any given source file can only include (directly or indirectly) one of the two headers.  If you tried to include both, you'd get the structure type redefined, and that is not allowed (even in C11, where you can have the same typedef name redefined as long as it defines the same type, but you still can't have two definitions of the structure type at the same scope in a single translation unit).

The most common way of ensuring that the types in the separate translation units are compatible is to use a single header to define the type and to include that header in both translation units.  However, if you think about it, the compiler doesn't know or care about whether that's what you do.  All that matters to it is that the text it sees after preprocessing identifies the same type.